# Magento2 - Changing the position of header content

Tags: magento2, css, header, toplinks, text

I want to make the **Free Shipping** content at the `top center` of the site but it is in right corner.

How to change the css for doing it?

Created a block on the admin panel and applied this code on `Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml`

```
 <referenceContainer name="header.panel"> 
            <block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" name="block_identifier"> 
                <arguments> 
                    <argument name="block_id" xsi:type="string">block_identifier</argument> 
                </arguments> 
            </block> 
        </referenceContainer>
```

Comment: are you trying to make a new bar in the header with a custom template?

Comment: yes and its a child theme of the magento luma

Comment: I have been trying to do it from a long time but no changes

Comment: Actually I've made a bar in header with my own custom block, template and CSS, so I could apply the styling however I wished. I'm not sure if this is your requirement. I chose `header.container` ad referenceContainer.

Comment: yes thats what I want at the top new grey line with the text free shipping in the place of signin and create account liks and language option

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add a new bar in the header, following code should work.
In your frontend's default.xml file put below code :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
     <head>
         <css src="Vendor_Module::css/vendor.shipping.bar.css"/>
    </head>
     <body>      
       <referenceContainer name="footer-container">
           <block class="Vendor\Module\Block\BottomBar" name="bottomshipping_bar" template="Vendor_Module::bar/bottomshippingbar.phtml">
               
           </block>
       </referenceContainer>
       <referenceContainer name="header.container">
           <block class="Vendor_Module\Block\TopBar" name="topshipping_bar" template="Vendor_Module::bar/topshippingbar.phtml">        
           </block>
       </referenceContainer>
       
   </body>
</page>
```

This code can add bars to both header and footers. In corresponding template and CSS files you can just do whatever you want with the bar i-e styling or php function. Hope, it helps.

Comment: its not working

Comment: 176 679 344 could you please access the system and resolve the issue if you have time.

Comment: How can I access your system? Moreover, this is pretty simple . I hope you are clear about blocks and templates in magento and are adding your html in template file. If you still getting error, feel free to ask!

Comment: do you know how to change the default content of the display notice option?

Answer (score 0):

```
<referenceContainer name="after.body.start">
                 <block class="Magento\RequireJs\Block\Html\Head\Config" name="requirejs-config"/>
               <block class**strong text**="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Js\Cookie" name="js_cookies" template="Magento_Theme::js/cookie.phtml"/>
                  <block class="Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Notices" name="global_notices" template="Magento_Theme::html/notices.phtml"/>
    
    </referenceContainer>
```